# How to get back to Windows after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Steps I performed to get into this problem.

1. Installed Ubuntu live server 18.04 LTS
2. Made bootable USB with rugs
3. Went to Windows boot manager from settings and entered boot any other USB or CD
4. Installed Ubuntu live server without internet because of some problem
5. Rebooted several times

Actual problem

1. Windows installed in UEFI
2. Ubuntu also in UEFI
3. No sign of Windows anywhere
4. Not able to perform `apt update` or download something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/217904/) and [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: There's no sense in reinstalling Windows if you don't need to. Maybe Ubuntu only overwrote the Windows bootloader but not the rest of Windows, so try repairing the Windows bootloader first. Rescatux is a pretty good UEFI compatible tool for repairing the Windows bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recovery disk you could ask Windows to reinstall his boot system.
If not, first try to get back Internet in ubuntu : plug an Ethernet cable if the problem is with Wifi.

Why did you install 18.04 server and not 20.04 Desktop ?